# Mapping a relationship from an entity to two other entities with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two different classes mapped with Fluent NHibernate

```
public class File1Map: ClassMap<File1> {
    CompositeId()
       .KeyProperty(x => x.IdFile)
       .KeyProperty(x => x.IdRow);

    HasMany(x => x.Errors).AsBag().KeyColumns.Add("IdFile", "IdRow");
}

public class File2Map: ClassMap<File2> {
    CompositeId()
       .KeyProperty(x => x.IdFile)
       .KeyProperty(x => x.IdRow);

    HasMany(x => x.Errors).AsBag().KeyColumns.Add("IdFile", "IdRow");
}

public class File1 {
    public int IdFile {get; set;}
    public int IdRow {get; set;}
    public List<Error> Errors {get; set;}
    // ...other properties different from File2
}

public class File2 {
    public int IdFile {get; set;}
    public int IdRow {get; set;}
    public List<Error> Errors {get; set;}
    // ...other properties different from File1
}
```

And a class with errors, containing description for each class.

```
public class ErrorMap: ClassMap<Error> {
    Map(p => p.IdFile);
    Map(p => p.IdRow);
    Map(p => p.Description);
}

public class Error {
    public int IdFile {get; set;}
    public int IdRow {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

How can i map `Error` to `File1` and `File2`?
Can I use has many for defining which column to use for the relation? (`Error` side.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using a base class**

For such case, mapping a base class is a usual solution. This requires your ids to be unique across `File1` and `File2`. (No composite id existing in `File1` can be found in `File2`, and conversely.) For having two distintc table for `File1` and `File2` while not having a table for the base class, you have to use ["table per concrete class strategy"](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete).

```
public class FileBaseMap: ClassMap<FileBase> {
    CompositeId()
       .KeyProperty(x => x.IdFile)
       .KeyProperty(x => x.IdRow);

    HasMany(x => x.Errors).AsBag().KeyColumns.Add("IdFile", "IdRow");
    // One table per concrete class.
    UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();
}

public class File1Map: SubclassMap<File1> {
    // Other properties mapping
}

public class File2Map: SubclassMap<File2> {
    // Other properties mapping
}

public abstract class FileBase {
    public int IdFile {get; set;}
    public int IdRow {get; set;}
    public List<Error> Errors {get; set;}
}

public class File1 : FileBase {
    // ...other properties different from File2
}

public class File2 : FileBase {
    // ...other properties different from File1
}
```

Then you can map your `Error` class to a `FileBase` property.

**Using separate foreign keys**

If you do not want to introduce a base class, or if you cannot guarantee uniqueness of your files ids across `File1` and `File2`, you have to map them as two separate collection of entities.

Your `Error` class would look something like:

```
public class Error {
    public int? IdFile1 {get; set;}
    public int? IdRow1 {get; set;}
    public int? IdFile2 {get; set;}
    public int? IdRow2 {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public File1 File1 {get; set;}
    public File2 File2 {get; set;}
}
```

**Using components**

Instead of mapping `Error` as an entity, you can map it as a [list of components](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/components.html#components-incollections)  in `File1` and `File2`. I do not know much Fluent, so I can only illustrate this with the hbm syntax. Up to you to find the appropriate Fluent calls.

This requires your ids to be unique across `File1` and `File2` too, otherwise errors may get mixed. (No composite id existing in `File1` should be found in `File2`, and conversely.)

```
<class name="File1">
  <!-- id and other properties here -->

  <bag name="Errors" table="Error">
    <key>
      <column name="IdFile" />
      <column name="IdRow" />
    </key>
    <composite-element class="Error">
      <property name="Description" />
    </composite-element>
  </bag>
</class>
```

And same for `File2`.

The `Error` class will not hold file id properties nor a file property, but only its `Description` and other properties if any.

If, apart the foreign key, you only have `Description` in your Error class, you may have better to remove that class and just map `Errors` as a [collection of element](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-ofvalues) (string in your case).

If you want to use a `set` rather than a `bag`, your component will have to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides, and `Description` must to be not nullable.

**Using [many-to-any](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-heterogeneous)**

Here again, I do not know if Fluent handles that. I never tried it either, and the documentation is quite succinct. Anyway, this is an exotic mapping to avoid as much as possible. It requires an additional column for identifying what is the ["any"](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-types-anymapping).
It would allow you to map the file reference in error as a single object property, without a base class. And it would support `File1` and `File2` having common ids.

**Notes:**

You should add a primary key on your `Error` class if you keep it as an entity, not a component. A technical one like a sequence id or whatever.

Better avoid using [composite ids](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid). Otherwise map them as [composite identifier](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/components.html#components-compositeid) and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in their component and in the entity.

You do not need to map the foreign key id in `Error`, this is a bit redundant with the mapping of file entities. You can have your `Error` class containing only its `Description` property and the file entity property.

So for the base class case it would be:

```
public class Error {
    public FileBase File {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```